# Pass variable to node-gyp when running npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I am using [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) to create a [Node.js addon](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/) and my `binding.gyp` contains some variables as follows:

```json
...
"link_settings": {
   "libraries": [
      "-lboost_program_options",
      "-lboost_log",
    ],
    "ldflags": [
       "-L<@(boost_root)/stage/lib",
       "-Wl,-rpath,<@(boost_root)/stage/lib",
     ]
  },
...
```

(complete gyp file from [here](https://blog.quaintous.com/2015/06/12/node-gyp-for-non-cpp-programmers/) ). I use `node-gyp configure --boost_root=/PATH/TO/BOOST build` to build the `C++` sources. The problem arises when I run `npm install` since it just calls `node-gyp rebuild` without any parameters.

Is there any way to do any of the following?

- Not run `node-gyp` rebuild when running `npm install`
- Pass parameters to `node-gyp` when running `npm install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lenghty discussion with @robertklep, I found out that passing the path as a [command line flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#command-line-flags) also solves the problem:

```
npm install --boost_path=/PATH/TO/BOOST
```

<del>however as he mentioned it is not known what happens if another package requires my package and tries to pass the parameter to it.</del>

**UPDATE:**

As it turns out this solution can be applied also if another package uses original package:

```
npm link /PATH/TO/ORIGINAL_PACKET --boost_path=/PATH/TO/BOOST
```

or if you have installed from directly from the package manager and now want to install it through the depending package:

```
npm install --boost_path=/PATH/TO/BOOST
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried myself, but according to [this](https://github.com/npm/read-package-json/blob/master/README.md#bindingsgyp) you can declare your own install script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts" : {
  "install" : "node-gyp configure --boost_root=/PATH/TO/BOOST build"
}
```

**EDIT**: just tried, works as advertised.

Instead of calling `node-gyp` from the `install` script, you can also call a shell script that you package as part of your module. For instance:

```
"scripts" : {
  "install" : "./scripts/build.sh"
}
```

The script would (somehow) determine the correct configuration settings and call `node-gyp` using them:

```
#!/bin/sh

...determine correct settings...

# call node-gyp
node-gyp configure --boost_root=$BOOST_PATH build
```

Make sure the script has executable permissions.

If you require the user to provide the path, the easiest would be to have them set an environment variable. Assuming it's called `BOOST_PATH`, this should work:

```
"scripts" : {
  "install" : "node-gyp configure --boost_root=\"$BOOST_PATH\" build"
}
```

The user could set it like so:

```
$ env BOOST_PATH=/PATH/TO/BOOST npm install yourmodule
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't formulate the problem precise enough. Since the path depends on the user/system trying to build the addon, I cannot hardcode it in `binding.gyp` or `package.json`.

Comment: I see you point. It would some kind of redirection if I'm not mistaken. But the question remains: how can the user building the package determine the correct path? Or do you suggest to use something like `read` to fetch user input?

Comment: A nice hack however, chapéu!

Comment: @YanFoto I would probably suggest using an environment variable, so they can use `env BOOST_PATH=/path/to/boost npm install`. I don't know Boost well enough, but it's relatively common for large libraries to offer CLI tools that output the relevant (lib/include) path (like `pkg-config`). If Boost has such an executable, you could call it from the build script.

Comment: I think that's the solution that I find best. Could you please please add it to your answer for future reference? I'd say that at the moment, there are no better solutions. right?

Comment: you may not believe it, but adding the `boost_path` as a [command line flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#command-line-flags) to npm solves the problem: `npm install --boost_pat=/PATH/TO/BOOST`. Shall I add it to the top of your answer?

Comment: @YanFoto haha :) I would suggest adding it as a separate answer (and since it's easier, feel free to accept that as the answer to your question!). One possible issue might be that if other projects declare your module as a dependency, it might not work anymore, but you'd have to try to make sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80672/discussion-between-yan-foto-and-robertklep).